# Installing Ubuntu on iMac - how to put .dmg of Ubuntu (which i converted from .iso) on a bootable flash drive?

Tags: mac

I have an iMac which I'm trying to dual boot macos and Ubuntu on.

I have converted the Ubuntu .iso to .dmg so that the Mac can actually open it at bootup.

Do I just copy the .dmg to the flash drive or what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dd program to copy the image to disk.

Step 1:  `$ diskutil list (to find name of disk)`
Step 2:  `$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskx`
Step 3:  `$ dd bs=1m if=path-to-image of=/dev/diskx`

I hope this helps! Please give me a shout if you need any more help.

Comment: thanks! the first two commands worked, but when i typed in the dd command, and included the correct path and everything, it told me that no such file exists. how do i write a path correctly? (i did /Desktop/ubuntu.dmg/)\      EDIT: I got the path correct. Now it's telling me permission denied.

Comment: try ~/Desktop/... note the tilde before the backslash

Comment: dd: /dev/disk1: Permission denied

Comment: You need to be in super-user mode so put "sudo" and that should give you permission. For example $ sudo dd ....

Comment: it seemed to have worked. possibly not, we'll find out when i reboot my computer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - it will take 10+ mins. Also, don't forget to hold down the option key on your iMac when booting to external media!

Comment: "it will take 10+ mins" - you are referring to the dd command?

Comment: Yeah - the output at the end should be something like xxxx bytes transferred in xxx seconds. After that just pop into your iMac and you should be good to go.